# How to return to contact form when got error in the form of page scrolling website

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

using Laravel for develop website in the website it is scrolling with the relevant ids as the navigation. my contact form like this

```
<div class="content">
@include('partials.alerts')
    <h1 class="heading">Contact Us</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Laboriosam ipsam repellat nostrum esse officiis unde quisquam corporis doloremque adipisci similique!</p>
    
    <form method="post" action="{{url('form')}}">
            {{csrf_field()}}
            <div class="form">
  <div class="input-flex">
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name*" /><br><br>
    <span style="color:red">@error('name'){{$message}}@enderror</span>
    <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="E-mail*" /><br><br>
    <span style="color:red">@error('email'){{$message}}@enderror</span>
    <input type="tel" class="full-width" name="telephone" placeholder="Phone number*" /><br><br>
    <span style="color:red">@error('telephone'){{$message}}@enderror</span>
    <textarea cols="2" rows="2" class="full-width" name="message" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
   </div>
  <button  class="conbtn" type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
</div>
```

and navigation is like this

```
<nav class="navbar">
    <div id="nav-close" class="fas fa-times"></div>
    <a href="#home">home</a>
    <a href="#idea">Idea</a>
    <a href="#about">about</a>
    <a href="#packages">packages</a>
    <a href="#reviews">reviews</a>
    <a href="#contact">contact</a> // navigation id for the contact
    <a href="#video">video</a>
</nav>
```

currentry when got some contact form error after click submit button of the contact form it is scrolling up to home section. but I need if got some error message in the contact form after click submit contact form submit button stay on contact section and display error messages. how could I do this?

Comment: Does it help if you add the hash tag to the action URL? `<form method="post" action="{{url('form')}}#contact">`

Comment: yes it is working well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The form will do a post request to the URL in the action attribute of the form. If you add the hash tag to the URL the page will navigate to the contact form in the load process (on the POST request).

```
<form method="post" action="{{url('form')}}#contact">
  {{csrf_field()}}
  ...
  <button  class="conbtn" type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

This will scroll to the contact form --  also when the content of the form is ok, so you could have a JavaScript that, when the page loads, removes the hash tag from the URL.